# Making a JTextArea serializable

Tags: java, sockets, nullpointerexception, jtextarea, serializable

When I try to send this class through a socket, all I get back is NullPointException. How would I make it so that I do not get NullPoint Exceptions?

```
public class Hick implements Serializable{
public JTextArea jta;
public Hick(){
jta = new JTextArea();
}
}
```

Comment: Post the code, how you try to send it.

Comment: I send it using a ObjectOutputStream. What i want to do is make jta serializable

Comment: Well, I can't just guess the problem, post the code, it might help. btw all swing components _are_ serializable.

Comment: And providing the stack trace might help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it with the following code it seems to work fine...

I would make sure that you can serialize the object locally first to rule out any potential problems.  If you still can't get it to load across the socket, then your socket code is at fault, not the serialization

```
public class TestSerialisation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestSerialisation();
    }

    public TestSerialisation() {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        Wrapper out = new Wrapper();
        System.out.println("Before = " + out.dump());
        try {
            try {
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("Test.out")));
                oos.writeObject(out);
            } finally {
                try {
                    oos.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }

            Wrapper in = null;
            try {
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("Test.out")));
                in = (Wrapper) ois.readObject();
            } finally {
                try {
                    ois.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }            
            System.out.println("After = " + (in == null ? "null" : in.dump()));            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
    }

    public static class Wrapper implements Serializable {

        private JTextArea textArea;

        public Wrapper() {
            textArea = new JTextArea("I'm some text");
        }

        public String dump() {
            return textArea.getText();
        }
    }
}
```

Also make sure you are running compatible versions of Java and (if my memory serves me properly) you have compatible versions of the serialized object on both ends.